# How to detect values changes after form builder and patchValue called?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this create and edit screen both in separated component. So in order to pump data in edit screen, I need to use patchValue and patch data with all the responses get back from API. 
So after patching all values I need to disable the Update button for better user experiences. Then whenever users trigger changes on the form , I will enable the Update button again.

The problem now is I wish to disable the button in form.valueChanges but seems failed because patchValue will trigger valueChanges once so is there anyway I can disable my button after all data been patched?
The boolean that control the button is isFormNoChanges stated below

```
constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private readonly agentService: AgentService,
  ) {

    this.agentService.getAgentMLRDetails().then((data: AgentList) => {
      this.agentDetails = data;
      this.injectValue(this.agentDetails);
    })

  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.onChanges();
  }

injectValue(data: AgentMLRList) {
    this.mlrForm.patchValue({
      entity: data.entityCode,
      agentCode: data.agentCode,
      productCode: data.product.productCode,
      coverageCode: data.coverage.coverageCode,
      startDate: data.startDate,
      endDate: data.endDate
    })

  }

onChanges() {
    this.mlrForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.isFormNoChanges = false
      })
}
```

Comment: try setTimeout.

Comment: can you explain more on this?

Comment: have a number with 3 possible values -1, 0 , 1. Disable the button if value is -1 or 0 and enable it if its 1. after Patch Value Set it to -1. In value changes have condition, if number is -1 , change it to 0, and if its 0 change it to 1.

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey do this and use skip operator as below :-**

```
this.mlrForm.valueChanges
      .pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(data => {
        this.isFormNoChanges = false
      })
```

**or use the solution i mentioned in comments above.**

**or use patchValue like**

```
patchValue({
      entity: data.entityCode,
      agentCode: data.agentCode,
      productCode: data.product.productCode,
      coverageCode: data.coverage.coverageCode,
      startDate: data.startDate,
      endDate: data.endDate
    }, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false })
```